# Node.js: Require locals

Tags: node.js, module, require, locals

### What I want

Is it possible to pass locals to a required module?
For example:

```
// in main.js
var words = { a: 'hello', b:'world'};
require('module.js', words);

// in module.js
console.log(words.a + ' ' + words.b) // --> Hello World
```

I'm asking this because in PHP when you require or include, the file which includes another files inherits it's variables, which is very useful in some cases, and I would be happy if this could be done in node.js too.

### What I have tried and didn't worked

```
 var words = { a: 'hello', b:'world'};
 require('module.js', words);
```

---

```
 var words = { a: 'hello', b:'world'};
 require('module.js');
```

Both of these gives `ReferenceError: words is not defined` when `words` is called in `module.js`

So is it possible at all without global variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is export it with an argument so you can pass it the variable.

`module.js`

```
module.exports = function(words){
    console.log(words.a + ' ' + words.b);
};
```

`main.js`

```
var words = { a: 'hello', b:'world'};
// Pass the words object to module
require('module')(words);
```

You can also chop off the .js in the require :)

Comment: this should work, but it's a bit dirty :\ isn't it possible without the module.exports function?

Comment: Unfortunately not that I'm aware. I hope someone provides a cleaner way of doing it, but my understanding of require is that everything works as modules. So when you require a function, to use outside of the module, you have to 'export' it to the application.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: What do you want to achieve?

If you want to export just a static function you can use [the answer from tehlulz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259401/node-js-require-locals/10259444#10259444). If you want to store an object inside the *exports* property and benefit from the require-caching node.js provides a (dirty) approach would be to you globals. I guess this is what you have tried.

Using JavaScript in a Web-Browser context you can use the `window` object to store global values. Node provides only one object that is global for all modules: the `process` object:

`main.js`

```
process.mysettings = { a : 5, b : 6};
var mod = require(mymod);
```

`mymod.js`

```
module.exports = { a : process.mysettings.a, b : process.mysettings.b, c : 7};
```

Alternatively if you are not interested in the exports caching you could do something like that:

`main.js`

```
var obj = require(mymod)(5,6);
```

`mymod.js`

```
module.exports = function(a,b){
 return { a : a, b : b, c : 7, d : function(){return "whatever";}};
};
```

Comment: `"So is it possible at all without global variables?"`